# I don’t understand my British Passport Expry date

Tags: passports, uk-citizens

I’m not sure how to read the expiry date on my British Passport, it states as follows;
Date of expiry 26 Mar/Mars 23
The date of issue states; 27 Dec/Dec 12
It doesn’t appear to state either the issue or expiry year. Can anyone advise me on this. Thank you.

Answer (score 9):

The date format used in all sections of the page is

> DD mon(English)/mon(French) YY

where DD is the two digit day, mon is a three (or four) letter abbreviation of the month and YY is a two digit abbreviation of the Gregorian year (so 2001 is 01 and 1970 is 70). Perhaps the easiest way of reassuring yourself of this is to look at the entry for date of birth (unless you happen to be fortunate enough that DD and YY are the same). This is a representation matching the (one version of the) ICAO standard for machine readable travel documents.

Together, this means your passport expires on the 26th of March 2023.